# wxTextValidation doesn't copy data from wxTextCtrl to wxString variable

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
//ctor
test=new wxString[n];
starr=new wxStaticText *[n];
tcarr=new wxTextCtrl *[n];

  wxBoxSizer *vbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
  wxBoxSizer *hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

  wxStaticBox *st = new wxStaticBox(this, -1, wxT("test"),wxPoint(5, 5), wxSize(240, 150));
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        starr[i] = new wxStaticText(this,-1,wxString::Format(wxT("test %i:"),i+1),wxPoint(20, 20+(i+1)*20));
        tcarr[i] = new wxTextCtrl(this, 32000+i, wxT(""),wxPoint(95, 20+(i+1)*20),wxDefaultSize,0,wxTextValidator(wxFILTER_NUMERIC,&test[i]));
        vbox->Add(starr[i],1);
        vbox->Add(tcarr[i],1);
   }
     wxButton *okButton = new wxButton(this, wxID_OK, wxT("Save"),
  wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(70, 30));


hbox->Add(okButton, 1);

vbox->Add(hbox, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER | wxTOP | wxBOTTOM, 10);

SetSizer(vbox);

Centre();


//header
private:
  wxString *test;
  wxStaticText **starr;
  wxTextCtrl **tcarr;
```

wxTextValidation doesn't copy data from wxTextCtrl to wxString variable:

When I click wxID_OK button and check value on test[0..n] I get empty wxString in each, What is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default wxValidator only copies the content of your control in the associated wxString when the control itself is "dismissed" (no idea whether this means destroyed or what). If you want to copy it as soon as the OK button is pressed, you have to do that explicitly. Try inserting this:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    tcarr[i]->GetValidator()->TransferFromWindow();
    wxMessageBox(test[i]); // just for debug
}
```

It worked fine for me (wxWidgets 3.0.2 on TDM-GCC-64).